# regexes in sed: matching a character that is not preceded or followed by a specific other character

Tags: regex, sed, csv

Assume a wrongly formatted csv snippet using semicolons as field terminator:

`abc;d" "e"f;"ijk"`

According to [RFC4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) a dquote inside a field should be represented by two dquotes:

`abc;d"" ""e""f;"ijk"`

I've tried to achieve this by a `sed` script that matches any dquote not preceeded or followed by the field terminator (here `;`):

```
echo 'abc;d" "e"f;"ijk"' | sed -e 's/\([^;]\)"\([^;]\)/\1""\2/g'
```

The result is almost good:

```
abc;d"" "e""f;"ijk"
```

except the double quote before the `e` is not matched and therefore not duplicated.

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work, since before and after the `e` there's no semicolon.

Comment: By dquote, do you mean a double quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second quote is not matched because the match would be `space quote e`, and the `space` is already consumed by the preceding `d quote space`.

This is a textbook example for [lookaround matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which matches but does not consume. Unfortunately lookaround matching is not implemented in `sed`. If I had to use `sed` for this, I would first replace valid quotes with some non-occurring character, then double all remaining quotes, then put the valid quotes back.

Perl has lookaround matching, which is (a little) easier on the eyes:

```
$ echo 'abc;d" "e"f;"ijk"' | perl -pe 's/(?<!;)"(?![;\n])/""/'g
abc;d"" ""e""f;"ijk"
```

Translation: a quote not preceded by the regex `;`, not followed by the regex `[;\n]`.

The \n is there because perl considers it part of the line, and will therefore match the last quote unless we forbid it.